# ValueError: the bucket does not exist, or is forbidden for access 'An error occurred (AccessDenied) when calling the CreateMultipartUpload

Tags: python, amazon-s3, amazon-kms, smart-open, multipart-upload

I am using python library `smart_open` to upload file (it would be big files) from python script to S3 bucket

Bucket has policy enforcing SSE with KMS

```
{
    "Version": "2012-10-17",
    "Id": "PutObjPolicy",
    "Statement": [
        {
            "Sid": "RequireKMSEncryption",
            "Effect": "Deny",
            "Principal": "*",
            "Action": "s3:PutObject",
            "Resource": "arn:aws:s3:::n-test-kms-123456789/*",
            "Condition": {
                "StringNotEquals": {
                    "s3:x-amz-server-side-encryption": "aws:kms"
                }
            }
        }
    ]
}
```

I try to open file to write by using:

```
from smart_open import open
--------
  with open(
    's3://' + BUCKET_NAME + '/robots.txt', 
    'w',
    transport_params = {
      'multipart_upload_kwargs': {
        'ServerSideEncryption': 'aws:kms',
        'SSEKMSKeyId': 'arn:aws:kms:us-east-2:1234567890:key/86fb3bf7-e9ef-4a93-bc64-35dcf1ca3c8d'
      },
      'client': boto3.client('s3')
    }
  ) as json_file:
```

I keep having error:

> ValueError: the bucket 'n-test-kms-123456789' does not exist, or is
> forbidden for access (ClientError('An error occurred (AccessDenied)
> when calling the CreateMultipartUpload operation: Access Denied'))

User and its IAM role has full permissions to that S3 bucket (including `CreateMultipartUpload`) - it seems like whole problem is limited to properly passing `'ServerSideEncryption': 'aws:kms'` to `transport_params`

What I ma doing wrong?

Comment: What permissions do you have? Are you allowed `CreateMultipartUpload` anywhere? The displayed policy does not `Allow` anything, it only `Deny`s an action.

Comment: User and its IAM role has full permissions to that S3 bucket (including `CreateMultipartUpload`) - it seems like whole problem is limited to properly passing `'ServerSideEncryption': 'aws:kms'` to `transport_params`

Answer (score 2):

```
with open(
  's3://' + BUCKET_NAME + '/robots.txt', 
  'w',
  transport_params = {
    'client_kwargs': {
      'S3.Client.create_multipart_upload': {
        'ServerSideEncryption': 'aws:kms'
      }
    },
    'client': boto3.client('s3')
  }
) as json_file:
```

I find proper settings of `transport_params` to pass SSE - also it was no need pass `KMSKeyId` in favor of default `aws/kms/s3` key